# Linear Equation by Elimination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What multiple of equation $1$ should be subtracted from equation $2$?

$Eq. (1): 2x-4y=6$

$Eq. (2): -x+5y=0$

After the elimination, solve the triangular system. If the right side changes to $(-6,0)$, what is the new solution?

**What I know:**

I know that I have to multiply equation $1$ $(Eq. 1)$ by $\frac{-1}2$ so that I can get $0\ 3$ for equation $2$ $(Eq. 2)$ by system of elimination giving me $2x-4y=6$ for $Eq. 1$ and $0x+3y=0$ for $Eq. 2$. However, when I use back substitution I get $y=0$, but the answer says that it should be $y=3$

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Beginning System:

$2x - 4y = 6$

$-x + 5y = 0$

Multiply the first equation by $\frac{1}{2}$

$x - 2y = 3$

$-x + 5y = 0$

Add equation 1 to equation 2:

$x - 2y = 3$

$0x + 3y = 3$.

From the lower equation, we deduce that $3y=3$, then $y = 1$.
We substitute $1$ in for $y$ of the upper equation to receive

$x -2 = 3$

Thus the solution of this linear system is $x = 5, y = 1$, or $(5, 1)$, if you prefer to use that notation.

$y=3$ will not produce a solution of this system. If you substitute 3 for $y$ in the original first equation, you get:

$2x -12 =6$, which shows that $x = 9$.

But, if you substitute $y=3$ into the second equation, you get:

$-x + 15 = 0$, which shows that $x = 15$.

As $15 \neq 9$, there is no $x$ that will produce a solution to the system of linear equations when $y =3$.

Comment: Ok, nice. I see that in my mistake I forgot to multiply the right hand side. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should have obtained $3y=3$ after the elimination (I'm guessing you forgot to perform the manipulations on the right-hand sides of the equations).  Why you should end up with $y=3$ is beyond me.

Comment: Multiply right hand side, got it. Thanks